# Adding files to zip java using memory while avoiding reserved file name problems

Tags: java, zip

I want to add, remove or modify files in zip using the most effective way possible.

Yes, you may say what I should do is to unzip/zip files into file system, but if there is a file with special name like '**aux**' or '**con**' , It **doesn't work in Windows** as they are DOS device names, and also there might be filename encoding issues that prevents the process from working proberly. Another reason I don't just unzip to file system and re-zip is that it is much more slower and takes more disk space than just using RAM.

In image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPuYG.png

Comment: Instead of using a `FileOutputStream`, try using a memory based stream, maybe something like [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer If I only use RAM, out of memory might occur, so I'm asking **how to use memory/ram efficiently** without problems like **described in image**

Comment: The only way I can think of would be to verify that use of the given names for a particular system.  Depending on what it is you're trying to do, you can copy chunks from one zip stream to another without touching the disk, but I would assume that the incoming and outgoing streams are connected to some device at some point...

Comment: @MadProgrammer What do you mean "some device" and "some point"?

Comment: If you're worried about running out memory, you need the stream (one point or the other - ie input and/or output) to be pushed to some device capable of storing it, like a disk

Comment: @MadProgrammeer Uhh, so you mean I have to make something like pipe on some deivce (e.g. disk) to copy chunks in zip. Ahh, I now understand what you mean, but how about determining the buffer size on RAM and another buffer on a device?

Comment: You can ascertain the amount of free ram available to Java, but it's always a little vague, using something like `Runtime#freeMemory`.  You could also use a sliding window style buffer.  Basically you determine some kind of threshold limit for the amount of time it might take to read/write (ie the turn around operation might be 25 milliseconds for example) and basically try and calculate (by going through the process (read/write) a few times) the optimal buffer size...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks a lot, but why didn't you post it as a question? xD

Comment: Because I wasn't sure of the question or if the suggestions would meet your requirements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a memory bases stream, like `ByteArrayOutputStream` to read/write the contents of the file.

The issue is the amount of available memory, because RAM is limited, you're going to need to store the output on something larger, like a disk eventually.

In order to try and optimism the process, you could set a preferred threshold for the read/write/process operation.

Basically you would run the process and calculate how long it took, based on the preferred threshold, adjust the buffer size for the next loop.

I would allow for a number of loops and average the time so your not trying to do fine control over the buffer that might actually slow you down

Comment: Thanks a lot, and also I reached 10 reputations xD